# Искажается изображение

Tags: c#, изображения, bitmap, png

Всем доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему используя код приведенный ниже (Перерисовка изображений формата PCX в Png) некоторые изображения получаются нормальными, а некоторые искаженными?

```
public static Bitmap PCX_GetImageFromFile(string filename, string img_name)
    {
        BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

        int totalSize = (int)binReader.BaseStream.Length;
        // Create a new bitmap.
        byte Manufactorer = binReader.ReadByte();
        byte Version = binReader.ReadByte();
        byte Encoding = binReader.ReadByte();
        byte BPP = binReader.ReadByte();
        short xmin = binReader.ReadInt16();
        short ymin = binReader.ReadInt16();
        short xmax = binReader.ReadInt16();
        short ymax = binReader.ReadInt16();
        short hres = binReader.ReadInt16();
        short vres = binReader.ReadInt16();
        byte[] colormap = new byte[48];
        colormap = binReader.ReadBytes(48);
        byte reserved = binReader.ReadByte();
        byte NPlanes = binReader.ReadByte();
        short BPL = binReader.ReadInt16();
        short PaletteInfo = binReader.ReadInt16();
        byte[] Filter = new byte[58];
        Filter = binReader.ReadBytes(58);

        byte[] pal = new byte[256 * 3];
        binReader.BaseStream.Seek(-256 * 3 - 1, SeekOrigin.End);
        byte palExists = binReader.ReadByte();
        if (palExists == 12)
            pal = binReader.ReadBytes(256 * 3);

        binReader.BaseStream.Seek(128, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        short width = (short)(xmax - xmin + 1);
        short height = (short)(ymax - ymin + 1);

        int totalData = totalSize - 769 - 128;

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        ColorPalette bpmPalette = bmp.Palette;
        for (int i = 0; i < bpmPalette.Entries.Length; i++)
            bpmPalette.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(pal[i * 3 + 0], pal[i * 3 + 1], pal[i * 3 + 2]);
        bmp.Palette = bpmPalette;

        // Lock the bitmap's bits.  
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
            bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            bmp.PixelFormat);

        // Get the address of the first line.
        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

        // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
        int bytes = bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
        // Copy the RGB values into the array.
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);


        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        byte count = 0;
        byte data = 0;

        try
        {
            while (totalData > 0)
            {
                count = 1;
                data = binReader.ReadByte();
                totalData--;
                if ((data & 192) == 192)
                {
                    count = (byte)(data & 63);
                    data = binReader.ReadByte();
                    totalData--;
                }
                for (int c = 0; c < count; c++)
                {
                    rgbValues[(y * width + x)] = data;
                    x++;
                    if (x > width - 1)
                    {
                        y++;
                        x = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);

        // Unlock the bits.
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        // Draw the modified image.
        // PictureBox for checking resulting image
        //pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        Bitmap bmps = (Bitmap)bmp.Clone();
        binReader.Close();
        bmp.Dispose();
        bmps.Save(/*Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()*/ "source/" + img_name + ".png");
        return bmp;
    }
```

Фото:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что делает ваш код приведенный в вопросе?

Comment: Перерисовывает изображение формата PCX в PNG

Comment: У меня такое было при не правильном выборе типа формата пикселов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл ошибку.
В этом цикле

```
for (int c = 0; c < count; c++)
            {
                rgbValues[(y * width + x)] = data;
                x++;
                if (x > width - 1)
                {
                    y++;
                    x = 0;
                }
            }
```

была неверная строка: `rgbValues[(y * width + x)] = data;`

Исправил на : `rgbValues[(y * bmpData.Stride + x * (BPP / 8))] = data;`
Теперь искажение пропало)

Если я всё правильно понял, то проблема была в игнорировании `bmpData.Stride` (Количество байтов в одной строке развертки изображения)